# Conditional rendering with fewer repetitions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have the following code in my component. You can see I have a lot of similar checks if the image exists or doesn't exist. I wonder if you have an idea of how to write this code block with fewer repetitions. E.g. checking for `image` only once.

```
{(!image || !element) && (
  <Typography align="center" variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
    Select an element and enter the image URL to see a preview.
  </Typography>
)}
{!image && element === ELEMENT.IMAGE_SMALL && (
  <img
    className={classes.imageElement}
    src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
    alt="Placeholder"
  />
)}
{!image && element === ELEMENT.IMAGE_LARGE && (
  <img
    className={classes.imageElement}
    src="https://via.placeholder.com/350"
    alt="Placeholder"
  />
)}
{image && element === ELEMENT.IMAGE_SMALL && (
  <img
    className={classes.imageElementSmall}
    src={image}
    alt="Half-Width Element"
  />
)}
{image && element === ELEMENT.IMAGE_LARGE && (
  <img
    className={classes.imageElementLarge}
    src={image}
    alt="Full-Width Element"
  />
)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepare the attributes and feed into the img,

```
getPros() {
    let propObj = {};
    if (image) {
        propObj = (element === ELEMENT.IMAGE_SMALL) ? 
        { className: classes.imageElementSmall, src: image, alt: 'Half-Width Element' } :
            { className: classes.imageElementLarge, src: image, alt: 'Full-Width Element' };
    } else {
        propObj = {
            className: classes.imageElement,
            src: `https://via.placeholder.com/${element === ELEMENT.IMAGE_SMALL ? '150' : '350'}`,
            alt: 'Placeholder'
        };
    }

    return propObj;
}


 {(!image || !element) && (
      <Typography align="center" variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
        Select an element and enter the image URL to see a preview.
      </Typography>
    )}


{element && <img {...getPros()}/>}
```

Answer (score 1):

## if statement around the className

I'm not super hapy with this implementation. But this would give you the result you want. Its justa bit hard to read.

```
{(!image || !element) && (
  <Typography align="center" variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
    Select an element and enter the image URL to see a preview.
  </Typography>
)}
  <img
    className={element === ELEMENT.IMAGE_LARGE ? classes.imageElementLarge : classes.imageElementSmall}
    src={image || element === ELEMENT.IMAGE_LARGE ? "https://via.placeholder.com/350" : "https://via.placeholder.com/150"}
    alt={!image ? "Placeholder" : element === ELEMENT.IMAGE_LARGE ? "Full-Width Element" : "Half-Width Element"}
  />
}
```

If you can I would determine the image and className before the render return that could be cleaner.

Comment: The idea behind this is pretty good, but it won't produce all of the cases. To be more precise it won't produce any of them.

Comment: Thank you @Joe I went with Sarun's solution as it gave me a bit more flexibility and makes it easier for others to understand my code. But smart approach.

Comment: Yes, good choice, thats what i meant by my final line. You should determine values above. Much better solution. Best of luck!